# World of Darkness tag synonyms

Tags: discussion, tags

Right now there are two questions ([553](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/553) and [686](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/686)) on the site about World of Darkness. 553 is tagged with both [[wod]](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wod) and [[world-of-darkness]](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/world-of-darkness), 686 with [world-of-darkness]. Which is the preferable parent tag for the purpose of tag synonyms?

Answer (score 4):

I'd be more inclined to use the world-of-darkness tag, primarily because of the extra descriptiveness over the abbreviation, which some people may not by familiar with.

Comment: Yeah, I don't think we gain any thing for tag brevity, and it's not as familiar as D&D (or dd, as we call it round these parts.)

Comment: Sounds good to me. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: Another issue may be search.  World-of-Darkness may be to our advantage when it comes to google.

Answer (score 1):

I've suggested [wod] as a synonym for [world-of-darkness]. If you have over a thousand rep, [come on over and vote](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/tags/world-of-darkness/synonyms).

Comment: May be a bit before you have all 4 votes. Since there are currently just 3 with 1000+ rep.

Comment: Yeah, and I don't get to both vote and suggest. Figured I'd flag it anyhow.